# A Taxi is going from point A to point B and makes 5 stopes on the way. 3 girls...

Tags: permutations, combinations

A Taxi is going from point A to point B and makes 5 stopes on the way. 3 girls enter the Taxi during the journey with 3 different tickets. How many different sets of tickets may they have had?

Comment: do you have any thoughts?

Comment: You need to enumerate the number of possible tickets any one rider can have.  That isn't exactly clear from the problem statement.  Does a "ticket" allow the rider to travel from one specific stop to another?  Or a certain number of stops?  Once you get that number $n$, the answer to your question is $\binom{n}{3}$.

Comment: You need to make clear what makes a ticket different from another ticket. Does one ticket define one start/enter point along the journey, as well as it's destination?

Comment: Also, please clarify the phrase "during the journey". Does that mean that each girl enters at one of the $5$ stops, or is the point $A$ also a possible entry point?

Comment: @nought Yes exactly..

Comment: @quasi Yes.. A can also be a point of entry..

Comment: Say we have one set of three distinct tickets, 1, 2, 3.  We can distribute those tickets to girl x, girl y, and girl z. And so they can be distributed among the three distinct girls, in $3!$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- A  ticket is defined by a starting point and an ending point.$\\[6pt]$

  Each girl enters the bus either at $A$ or at one of the $5$ stops along the way.

Consider the $7$ points consisting of $A,B$ and the $5$ stops.

Of those, every pair of distinct points is a possible ticket.

Thus, there are $\binom{7}{2} = 21$ possible tickets.

The count we want is the number of sets of $3$ distinct tickets, which is just $\binom{21}{3} = 1330.$

Note: I interpreted "how many different sets of tickets", as just that, with no consideration of who has which ticket. If the tickets are regarded as "named" (i.e., it matters who has which ticket), then just multiply the above answer by $6$.

Comment: But there is also the permutation of those three distinct tickets, given that the girls are not likely seen as identical.

Comment: I interpreted it as just "how many sets of tickets", with no consideration of who had which ticket.

Comment: Yes, I understand; you've covered both interpretations now! +1